# How can I pass a user input string to a function as arguments in a python script?

Tags: python

I want to pass a user input string to a function, using the space separated words as it's arguments. However, what makes this a problem is that I don't know how many arguments the user will give.

Comment: Is this through in-program input or passing command line arguments to the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def your_function(*args):
    # 'args' is now a list that contains all of the arguments
    ...do stuff...

input_args = user_string.split()
your_function(*input_args) # Convert a list into the arguments to a function
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

Granted, if you're the one designing the function, you could just design it to accept a list as a single argument, instead of requiring separate arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way, using str.split and argument unpacking:

```
f(*the_input.split(' '))
```

However, this won't perform any conversions (all arguments will still be strings) and split has a few caveats (e.g. `'1,,2'.split(',') == ['1', '', '2']`; refer to docs).

Comment: In the vast majority of cases where people write `.split(' ')` what they really should have written is `.split()`.

Comment: the example you set, is not a caveat, it's just logical! (because it split at the commas)

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options. You can make the function take a list of arguments:

```
def fn(arg_list):
    #process

fn(["Here", "are", "some", "args"]) #note that this is being passed as a single list parameter
```

Or you can collect the arguments in an arbitrary argument list:

```
def fn(*arg_tuple):
    #process

fn("Here", "are", "some", "args") #this is being passed as four separate string parameters
```

In both cases, `arg_list` and `arg_tuple` will be nearly identical, the only difference being that one is a list and the other a tuple: `["Here, "are", "some", "args"]` or `("Here", "are", "some", "args")`.